# Eclipse, workspaces, DropBox and source control

Tags: windows-7, sync, eclipse, dropbox

Eclipse has an idea I've always been kinda uncomfortable with - the idea of the workspace.

The workspace is that folder you store ALL your projects in. You cannot store projects outside the workspace.  There is a painful import/export procedure you are subjected to to bring projects into your workspace.  There's an enormous `.meta` folder inside the root of workspace that always seems to keep growing.

In GIT and other source control packages, you can easily stop a folder from being committed (namely the `.meta` folder) by using a `.IGNORE` file. Fine.

But if you want to also sync the source of small projects you *don't* want to bother commiting to a repository, you're kind of screwed here. The [DropBox ignore folder feature isn't complete](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=3552) [2](https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/2005/selective-pause).  I for example use Texclipse to develop LaTeX documents.  Of course every document in Texclipse must be within the Workspace folder, which means I can't sync these files to dropbox easily (without syncing the massive `.meta` folder as well).

Is there a clever workaround to sync my Eclipse workspace folder, excluding the `.meta` folder, to my Dropbox?

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox can follow symbolic links when syncing files and folders. You should be able to create symlinks from your Dropbox folder, to the folders you want to sync.

Also, I have not used Dropbox in awhile, but I believe it has a 'Selective Sync' feature now. This may be similar to the symlinks solution (i.e. you have to select all the folders you want, rather than only the few folders you don't want).

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm on Windows.

Comment: [link](http://www.dropbox.com/help/175) Dropbox Selective Sync for Windows

Comment: @bobobobo You can create symbolic links in Windows using the `mklink /D` command.